# Inspect sqlalchemy mock connection

Tags: python, view, sqlalchemy

I am trying to learn how to create a view in sqlalchemy. This tutorial https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Views (SQLAlchemy 1.4, 2.0 version) works well, however, I would like to print schema instead of actually applying it. So I am trying to combine the above tutorial with https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/metadata_schema.html#how-can-i-get-the-create-table-drop-table-output-as-a-string .

When I change
`engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)`
to

```
def dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))

engine = create_mock_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://", dump)
```

it throws on
`sqlalchemy.inspect(connection)`
saying
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.mock.MockConnection'>`

On the other hand, it works fine when I remove my view and keep only tables.

Is it possible to inspect mocked connection?

Script to recreate the problem:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDLElement
from sqlalchemy.sql import table


class CreateView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name, selectable):
        self.name = name
        self.selectable = selectable


class DropView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


@compiler.compiles(CreateView)
def _create_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "CREATE VIEW %s AS %s" % (
        element.name,
        compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.selectable, literal_binds=True),
    )


@compiler.compiles(DropView)
def _drop_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "DROP VIEW %s" % (element.name)


def view_exists(ddl, target, connection, **kw):
    return ddl.name in sa.inspect(connection).get_view_names()


def view_doesnt_exist(ddl, target, connection, **kw):
    return not view_exists(ddl, target, connection, **kw)


def view(name, metadata, selectable):
    t = table(name)

    t._columns._populate_separate_keys(
        col._make_proxy(t) for col in selectable.selected_columns
    )

    sa.event.listen(
        metadata,
        "after_create",
        CreateView(name, selectable).execute_if(callable_=view_doesnt_exist),
    )
    sa.event.listen(
        metadata, "before_drop", DropView(name).execute_if(callable_=view_exists)
    )
    return t


if __name__ == "__main__":
    metadata = sa.MetaData()
    stuff = sa.Table(
        "stuff",
        metadata,
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column("data", sa.String(50)),
    )

    more_stuff = sa.Table(
        "more_stuff",
        metadata,
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column("stuff_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("stuff.id")),
        sa.Column("data", sa.String(50)),
    )

    # the .label() is to suit SQLite which needs explicit label names
    # to be given when creating the view
    # See http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html
    stuff_view = view(
        "stuff_view",
        metadata,
        sa.select(
            stuff.c.id.label("id"),
            stuff.c.data.label("data"),
            more_stuff.c.data.label("moredata"),
        )
        .select_from(stuff.join(more_stuff))
        .where(stuff.c.data.like(("%orange%"))),
    )

    assert stuff_view.primary_key == [stuff_view.c.id]

    def dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
        print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))

    engine = sa.create_mock_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://", dump)
    
    metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=False)
```